# Symmetric-monoidal-associative smash product up to homotopy

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy, symmetric-monoidal-categories, stable-homotopy-category

I am thinking about sequential spectra. I am trying to figure out if the smash product [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sequential+spectrum) is symmetric monoidal associative *up to homotopy*. See definition 3.16 in the above.

Recall that a sequential spectrum consists of a sequence of based connected spaces $X_n$ with maps $X_n \rightarrow \Omega Y_n$, or equivalently maps $\Sigma X_n \rightarrow Y_n$.

In searching for a convenient construction of the stable homotopy category which features more of the mutually exclusive properties established [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404991900306), I thought of the concept of a "pre-map":

**Premaps:** Here I would like to use a "pre-map" of spectra. To define this, let X and Y be sequential spectra. A pre-map $f : X \rightarrow Y$ consists of maps $f : X_n \rightarrow Y_n$ which produce commutative diagrams involving the structure maps in the stable homotopy category.

The rationale is that, since the stable homotopy category has all of the five properties in the paper linked above, these can be lifted, not to a map, but at least to a premap. This more lax condition could remove the foundational troubles associated to wedge with $S^1$ and the related coherence.

The main things I wanted to try first is showing that sequential spectra with premaps forms a symmetric monoidal category:

**Symmetry:** To define pre-symmetry, let $X$ and $Y$ be sequential spectra. I would like to construct a premaps $f : X \wedge Y \rightarrow Y \wedge X$ and $g : Y \wedge X \rightarrow X \wedge Y$.

**Preassociativity:** To define pre-symmetry, let $X$ and $Y$ be sequential spectra. I would like to construct a premaps $f : X \wedge (Y \wedge Z)  \rightarrow (X \wedge Y) \wedge Z$ and $g : (X \wedge Y) \wedge Z \rightarrow X \wedge (Y \wedge Z)$.

In sum, I imagine a category of spectra whose hom component consists of these premaps instead, and I suspect that one can always lift the desirable properties of the stable homotopy category to the category of sequential spectra with *premaps* as maps. I'd love to hear about any convenience that ensures, particularly the five properties (A1)-(A5) in the paper by Gaunce Lewis Jr. linked to above.

Comment: For clarification, in your definition of a premap, are the maps $X_n  \to Y_n$ also in the stable homotopy category, or is just the commutativity checked there?

Comment: @TylerLawson the commutativity is just checked there, while the maps are not in it. P.S. isn't it possible to lift such a map in the derived category? In this sense, I suspect that there is not a critical difference, even though I want the map to be in the pre-derived category of spaces. P.P.S. you probably meant Xₙ ⭢ Yₙ is a map in the homotopy category as it is prior to the construction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't just have a problem with commutativity of the structure maps in the stable category; there are also not enough premaps to construct a map $\tau$ representing the twist automorphism in the stable category.
$\newcommand{\SS}{\mathbb{S}}$

For any $n$, there is a sequential spectrum $\SS^{-n}$ such that
$$
(\SS^{-n})_k = \begin{cases}
\ast &\text{if }k < n,\\
S^{k-n} &\text{if }k \geq n,
\end{cases}
$$
with structure maps being isomorphisms in degrees $n$ and above. These satisfy $\SS^{-n} \wedge \SS^{-m} \simeq \SS^{-(n+m)}$ (isomorphic using actual maps of sequential spectra, and hence also using premaps). These represent the negative spheres in the stable homotopy category.

Any premap $\SS^{-n} \to \SS^{-n}$ consists of maps $f_k: S^{k-n} \to S^{k-n}$. For $k \geq n$, the premap condition asks that $\Sigma f_k$ and $f_{k+1}$ be equivalent in the stable homotopy category. But maps between spheres are completely classified, up to (stable) homotopy, by their degree, and so being a premap is the same as asking all of the $f_k$ to have the same degree.

However, the map $f_n$ is a (pointed) map $S^0 \to S^0$, and this can only have degree 0 or 1. So premaps $\SS^{-n} \to \SS^{-n}$ can only have degree 0 or 1.

If we choose an isomorphism $\SS^{-n} \wedge \SS^{-n} \to \SS^{-(2n)}$, any choice of $\tau: \SS^{-n} \wedge \SS^{-n} \to \SS^{-n} \wedge \SS^{-n}$ becomes isomorphic to a self-map of $\SS^{-(2n)}$, and this means that the only choice is for it to have degree 1. The twist self-map of $\SS^{-n}$ in the stable homotopy category, however, has degree $(-1)^n$.

(If you ask for $\tau$ to be *natural* in $X$ and $Y$, you can prove that $\tau$ can't exist.)

One intuition from this is that sequential spectra are based on $\mathbb{N}$, which is "too symmetric" for the stable homotopy category.

Different approaches to solving Lewis' objections have solved this in different ways.

- Adams used a "cells now, maps later" approach to ensure that enough maps were defined.
- $\SS$-modules (EKMM) imposed a "spectrification" / $\Omega$-spectrum condition so that any map in the stable homotopy category could automatically be realized by a map/premap.
- Symmetric spectra (HSS) deliberately added extra symmetry isomorphisms.
- Spectra as in Higher Algebra (Lurie) also imposes an $\Omega$-spectrum condition.
- It's also possible to, instead, use even spheres: use S^2 instead of S^1.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. I'm just now getting the hang of this area. I notice you used a negative-dimension for the shifted sphere spectrum in question. On the off-chance you can comment on whether this applies to infinite loop spaces as well, that would be very much appreciated!

Comment: @Cayley-Hamilton That really depends on the way that you model infinite loop spaces; there are several. Since you're asking a number of questions about Lewis' objections, it seems that you are unsatisfied with the ways that other model for stable homotopy theory have addressed them. Is there a particular application that you have in mind?